# What does 'null' mean when preceding a value in a SELECT statement?

Tags: sql, t-sql

Apologies if this has been asked before but I can't seem to find a relevant answer. It looks like it should be rather simple.

I'm looking at a store procedure (in Sql Server 2008) that includes a select statement similar to the following:

```
SELECT id, name, null revisedDate
FROM MyTable
```

What does 'null' mean when preceding the column 'revisedDate'? Does this mean make the returned column values null regardless? I thought it might be a way of giving it a default value of null, but then surely if there's no value then it would return null anyway.

Comment: `null as [revisedDate]` is more clear, but the 'as' is optional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It simply means that you are including a hardcoded `NULL` value in your result set. Further `revisedDate` is the name given to that column. For every row in the result set, this column will show `NULL`.

Comment: Ok, so it's as I expected. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming TSQL..
Im pretty sure that that will just return a column of nulls under the heading revisedDate. It wont bring back values form any column as in SQL syntax this is the equivelent of null as revisedDate

Hth
O